# Efficient numerical methods to estimate ARMA models?

Tags: time-series, estimation, arima, optimization, numerics

I mean exact likelihood based estimation instead of these LS methods.

There are more general nonlinear optimization methods, but in terms of performance, are there any specific methods for this type of problems?

Comment: One reasonably fast way to *evaluate* the likelihood is via the Kalman Filter. I believe at least some ML routines for ARMA models make use of this approach.

Comment: @Glen_b: Thanks, but since it is rather straight forward to compute the Hessian for ARMA with normal errors, I think the computation of likelihood is trivial in such cases...

Comment: It's straightforward in a variety of ways... but you asked about *performance*, not "triviality". Any optimization will involve function evaluations, so reasonably efficient methods become relevant, even if it's not hard to do it in a bunch of ways.

Comment: @Glen_b: I mean since solving the problem involves the computation of Hessian (typical), which is N^2 in size, so the evaluation of functions (N) is not likely to be the bottleneck of the performance when Hessian is computed analytically.